# tumblr tag - footer size needs to be relevant to tags

Tags: html, css, tags, footer

I've looked around a bit and my question is pretty specific so I don't think anyone else has asked anything like this yet (I apologize if it has been asked about though and would love to be directed to the answer!).

Anyway, I have a similar problem to [lutnik here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22588229/tumblr-tags-dont-fit-on-footer-of-posts) except that my tags fit nicely into a single line on my footer. The default of the theme has the tag overflow being hidden but I want all my tags to show. Unfortunately, when they all show [this happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3G5G.png).

Is there some kind of code to make the footer (the blue part) extend down depending on how many tags there are?

I've been comparing this current theme to another one that does seem to have some kind of extension effect on its footer so I know it's possible but comparing the codes has been driving me crazy because nothing is popping out at me to cause that kind of effect (then again I'm a complete beginner at this so...).

From what I can see the relevant parts are the info section of the code (what the theme maker decided to call that footer I guess?) and the tag section.

```css
/* CONTENT */

    .info {
        height: 25px;
        float:center;
        padding-top:2px;
        margin-top:10px;
        opacity:0.7;
        text-align:center;
        font-size:8px;
        letter-spacing:1px;
        background-color: {color:Info BG};
        background-image:url('{image:Info BG}');
        color:{color:Link};
        border-top: 1px solid {color:Info Border};
        border-bottom: 2px solid {color:Info Border};
        width: 560px;  
        margin-left:-30px;
        text-transform:uppercase;
        transition-duration: 0.6s;  
        -moz-transition-duration: 0.6s;  
        -webkit-transition-duration: 0.6s;  
        -o-transition-duration: 0.6s; }
    
    .info a {
        font-size:8px;
        padding-right:10px;}

    /* TAGS */

    .tags {
        padding-top:2px;
        height:10px;
        opacity:0.8;
        overflow: visible;
        font-size:8px;
        text-transform:uppercase;}
    
    .tags a {
        padding-right:6px;
        color:#000000;
        font-size:8px;}
```

Here's the [entire code](http://pastebin.com/RZNrBZNd) for the theme I'm currently using.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! And please let me know if any more information is needed.

Answer (score 0):

OH! NEVERMIND. I solved it!

I just had to delete the "height" part of the code from ".info" to stop the footer from being a fixed height and then delete the "height" from ".tags" to prevent the overflow from kicking in.